# Проверка: является ли исходная строка путём к файлу

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть вводимая пользователем строка, которая должна иметь вид полного пути к файлу, подхватывая её программа работает с указанным в файлом, как бы сделать так, чтобы проверка правильности ввода происходила до (!FileExist),т.к. если по указаной строке файл необходимо создавать, то программа вылетит с необработанным исключением.
наработки:

```
string pattern = @"([a-zA-Z]://)((/w+//)+|(/w+./w+))"
```

Но у меня есть подозрения что эта конструкция будет работать неверно. 
Знающие, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]:\/)((\w+\/)*(\w+.\w+)) вот такое получилось

Comment: *"чтобы проверка .. происходила до (!FileExist),т.к. если по указаной строке файл необходимо создавать, то программа вылетит с необработанным исключением"*. Лучше исправить вот это, чем пытаться регуляркой проверить путь, который все равно может не существовать.

Comment: А исключение поймать кто мешает? Оно и так может вылететь, если, допустим, в выбранное место нельзя писать или не существует самой папки, куда требуется записать файл даже если путь правильный. Так что лучше не мучаться с проверкой через регекспы, а ловить и обрабатывать исключения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.exists), для этого вместо `System.IO.File.Exists` лучше использовать `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars`, который возвращает массив `char[]` из недопустимых символов.

Так же лучше проверять на `null`, и на поддерживаемый формат имени (как например наличие `:` внутри имени файла/папки)

т.е. проверять правильность ввода так:

```
    private bool isFileNameValid(string fileName)
    {
        if ((fileName == null) || (fileName.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) != -1))
            return false;
        try
        {
            var tempFileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Поставил минус: http://i4.imageban.ru/out/2017/02/21/e6bddc318a420720659d433b7a0045e4.png

Comment: @Андрей, точно, двоеточие `:` в середине в этом случае (`myPath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) == -1`) будет считаться допустимым именем файла. Изменил ответ.

Comment: А еще хорошо бы проверять и длину строки